# Improve webview performance - android

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I'm developing an application that use a webview which loads an Html & javascript files.

but the performance was too bad when its display the content!

I've tried many solutions like:

```
        webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH); 
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE); 
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
```

but it's still remain the same.

Any advice or tips to enhance the performance?

Comment: Were you able to find any solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

If there's only some few components of your webview that is slow or laggy, try adding this to the elements css:

```
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

This has been the only speedhack that really had a effect on my webview. But be careful not to overuse it! (you can read more about the hack in [this article](http://www.tricedesigns.com/2013/03/11/performance-ux-considerations-for-successful-phonegap-apps/).)

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: to be more specific the content is viewed like a mind map. so, the performance of the mind map is too bad. as ex. when your going to expand a node.